# cisco router loses configuration on reload even after saving it

Tags: cisco, ios

I'm configuring a Cisco 3640 and it's not saving simple things like my hostname.
I've tried with 'wr' and 'copy running-config startup-config'. Also erased the configuration but no luck.
There's no error whatsoever when running the above commands.
Is my flash bad?
Anyway I can debug this more thoroughly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have a configuration register at the wrong setting.  For instance, setting: confreg 0x2142 at an rommon will boot the router to a fresh/default mode.  Trying entering config-register 0x2102 from an enable prompt to got back to booting from your configuration

Answer (score 4):

Rommon is probably set to ignore the startup-config.

Do a 'show version' and see if the configuration register is 0x2142.  If it is you will have to change this to 0x2102.

Edit: Points to Andy he posted first.

Someone got half way through a password reset and gave up.  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_password_recovery09186a0080094774.shtml